# How do I delete a whole line containing a match in a multiline C# regex?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a set of lines in a string:

```
alksjdlaksj asdkjf
askldjfak askdjfk
ksdjfk **Bogus** alskdjfalksdj
sadkljfal skdjfkd
```

and need to delete the lines with 'Bogus' in them.  I can use

```
Regex.Replace(result, @"^.*Bogus.*$", "", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

to detect and wipeout the said line.  However, it leaves a blank line.  Can I use this regex statement to clear out the blank line as well?

Comment: Try using `@"^.*Bogus.*\n$", "", RegexOptions.Multiline);`, I believe that would do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your regex non-multiline... then add a linebreak at the end so that it is part of the match.

Example:

```
(^|\n).*Bogus.*\n?
```

Comment: I'll try that. Do I need to worry about \r's and other different kinds of line breaks?

Comment: What has everybody got against Multiline mode? `(?m)^.*Bogus.*\n*` works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

If possible in your scenario, you could just use plain `String.Contains()`, i.e.

```
var result = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, sourceString.Split(Environment.NewLine)
    .Where(line => !line.Contains("Bogus")).ToArray());
```